# Reference for closed categories and monoidal categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, homological-algebra, tensor-products, monoidal-categories

I'm looking for a book that:

- Defines closed categories separately from monoidal categories, and
  then proves in detail that the structure induced by a left adjoint to the
  internal hom is closed monoidal, and furthermore that this monoidal
  closed structure coincides with the one obtained from a right adjoint
  to the tensor product, if it exists.
- Develops intuition for extranatural transformations.
- Discusses the closed monoidal structure of $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(R\mathsf{Mod})$ in detail.

Comment: At least some of what you're asking for is in "closed categories" by Eilenberg and Kelly, in Proceedings of the Conference on Categorical Algebra, 1966, pp 421-562. Does this help?

Comment: @TomHirschowitz thanks for the reference! I was hoping for something more modern and detailed, but I'll try to make the most of it for now.

Comment: A modern (seemingly little-known) reference for closed categories is *Skew-Closed Categories* by Ross Street, available at http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6522v3, which is "a modern reworking of Eilenberg-Kelly's original paper".